# ServiceStack: IService & IRestService

Tags: rest, servicestack

I had some good results with implementing Rest Web Services with ServiceStack Framework, but I noticed somethings in samples I would like some more information.

1. I have currently created a Service based on `IService` interface. What is the differences with using `IRestServiceBase`? When should I use either one or the other (my web service has routes so it's REST already right)?
2. What is the difference between these 2 syntaxes?

   ```
   MyEvent : RestServiceBase <Event>
   public override object OnGet(...)
   ```

   and

   ```
   MyEvent : IService
   public object Get(...)
   ```

   The one I use with my `IService` is the second version, is version one being more 'REST' than the other? I tested both and did same results.
3. I have not used attributes `[DataMember]` or `[DataContract]` the way it's done on WCF, in which situation do I have to use this? (to speak the truth I can really pass on adding this useless information).
4. In Movie sample, what are `Interfaces : IRestGetService`? What is their purpose when my class already has `IService`?

Comment: I wouldn't call `[DataMember]` and `[DataContract]` "useless info", I would suggest that you apply them because they set the method names as far as the public interface for your service is concerned so you can rename the methods on the interface but leave the `Name` in the attribute and it means that consumers of your service will continue to work without re-generating/recompiling their code. This helps with version changes of your service.

Comment: ok but when using REST, i though i only needed to manage 'Routes' attribute ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ServiceStack, I'm referring to best practices for WCF services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [newer style api](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API) uses the `Service` base class. Your service will act just like it did when using RestServiceBase but the new api has a bunch of added benefits which are described in the documentation.

Use the `[DataMember]` and `[DataContract]` attributes when [supporting SOAP endpoints](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support).

`IRestGetService` is [marked obsolete](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IRestGetService.cs) and you should move to the new style api. In the new api, [interfaces](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IService.cs) such as `IGet` and `IPost` can be used to enforce the correct method signatures but are not required.

Comment: Also DataMember and DataContract are useful when you might want to use [IgnoreDataMember] to hide properties.